# how to dynamically set an value in json read from file in Karate

Tags: karate

I want to dynamically set value for some elements in JSON(read from a file) using data driven feature of KARATE framework. Here are more details:

```
request.json -> { wheels : <wheel>, color: '<color>' }
```

Feature: Read json input from file and iterate over data table values

Background:

```
* url ''
* def reqJson = read('request.json') 
* print reqJson
```

Scenario Outline: Test file read

```
# I want to avoid writing below set statements for each element in request
#* set reqJson.wheels = <wheel>
#* set reqJson.color = '<color>'

Given path ''
And request reqJson
When method POST
Then status 200
And match response contains {mode: '<result>'}

Examples:

| wheel | color | result  |
| 4     | red   | car     |
| 2     | any   | bicycle |
```

I am developing automation framework using Karate, my intention is to save sample request in JSON file for a given API and then during execution I want element values to be replaced with the ones given in the table above.I don't want to write set statement for each element either(commented lines above)

P.S.: I tried with calling other feature file using table approach. However, I want to keep one feature file per API, hence want to know if there is any way possible for the above approach

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have missed [embedded expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions) which is simpler than the `set` keyword in many cases, especially when reading from files.

For example:

`request.json -> { wheels : '#(wheels)', color: '#(color)' }`

And then this would work:

```
* def wheels = 4
* def color = 'blue'
* def reqJson = read('request.json')
* match reqJson == { wheels: 4, color: 'blue' }
```

If you go through the [demo examples](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo) you will get plenty of other ideas. For example:

```
* table rows
| wheels | color  | result |
|      4 | 'blue' | 'car'  |
|      2 | 'red'  | 'bike' |

* call read('make-request.feature') rows
```

And where `make-request.feature` is:

```
Given path ''
And request { wheels: '#(wheels)', color: '#(color)' }
When method POST
Then status 200
And match response contains { mode: '#(result)' }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Peter, both approaches worked perfectly fine. Truly impressed by the Karate framework's rich & cool features!

Comment: Hi Peter, I did upvote but could see this message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."