# How to pass parameter in a JSON file in karate

Tags: karate

I have my request body in a `*.json` file and same `*.json` request body with different parameters is used in multiple test scenarios. How to pass variables in this scenarios.

I tried below

```
* def requestBody = call read ('successScenario.json') { id: 'U123', age: 23, date: currentDate }
And request requestBody
```

Please note I can't use examples as one of my variable is currentDate function so how to pass currentDate variable via examples.

This is not working. If I don't pass parameters here it works fine. I don't want to define these parameters in `karate-config.js` file as it is scenario dependent variables.

When I use above in `*.js` file it works fine but the response body is JSON i can't make a *.js file for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that there is no such thing as `call read('some.json')`. In other words, JSON is not something you can `call`.

Please take some time to read this part of the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#call-vs-read

If you want to "data drive" a JSON file, use "embedded expressions".

This is explained well here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50093102/143475